# Create structural directive that applies 2 way binding to its params

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I currently need to do the following in a few places to ensure that dialogs are only present in the DOM when opened.

```
<vcd-modal *ngIf="modalOpen" [(open)]="modalOpen" ...>
```

I would like to create a directive for syntax sugar that looks like `<vcd-modal *vcdModalOpen[modalOpen]>` which takes care of the double binding for me. I have the following code

```
import {AfterViewChecked, Directive, EmbeddedViewRef, Input, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef} from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
    selector: "vcd-modal[vcdModalOpen]"
})
export class ModalOpenDirective implements AfterViewChecked {

    private hasView = false;

    // Unsure how to get this, this is the component where 
    // `this.modalOpen` is defined
    private parent: any;

    constructor(
        private modal: VcdModalComponent,
        private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
        private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef) {

    }

    @Input() set vcdModalOpen(condition: boolean) {
        if (!condition && !this.hasView) {
            this.viewContainer.clear();
            this.hasView = false;
            // Need to unsubscribe from previously created components
        } else if (condition && this.hasView) {
            this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
            this.hasView = true;

            // Bind one from modal to the parent
            this.modal.openChange.subscribe((open) => {
                this.parent.modalOpen = open;     
            });

            // Bind from the parent to the modal
            const oldNgOnChanges = this.parent.ngOnChanges;
            this.parent.ngOnChanges = (changes: SimpleChanges) => {
                oldNgOnChanges.call(this, changes);
                this.model.open = this.parentModalOpen;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

It does not work because of the following:

- I have no way of knowing what the parent is so I can set its `modalOpen` flag
- The property name of the parent's `modalOpen` state could be anything, not necessarily `modalOpen` but the expression has already been evaluated by Angular

I figured I could pass in the parent and the property name as a string, but I would lose type safety and it would end up requiring more code than my initial example with an `*ngIf` and a double binding.

Is there a way to achieve this syntax sugar I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You pass the directive an subject. When the directive receives the subject the dialog is opened, and when the dialog closes the directive emits the result.

component.ts

```
@Component({})
export class MyComponent {
  public modalOpen$: Subject<Subject<any>> = new Subject();

  public function open() {
      const s = new Subject();
      s.subscribe(result => {
          console.log('dialog result', result);
      });
      this.modalOpen$.next(s);
  }
}
```

component.html

```
<vcd-modal *ngIf="modalOpen$ | async">
```

Now you change your directive to use the subject.

```
@Directive({...})
export class ModalOpenDirective implements AfterViewChecked {
    private hasView = false;

    constructor(
        private modal: VcdModalComponent,
        private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
        private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef) {
    }

    @Input() set vcdModalOpen(parent: Subject<any>) {
        if (!parent && !this.hasView) {
            this.viewContainer.clear();
            this.hasView = false;      
        } else if (parent && this.hasView) {
            this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
            this.hasView = true;

            this.modal.openChange.subscribe((open) => {
            // ^^ I'm not sure what this is but emit it back to the parent
                parent.next(open);     
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The above works based on the idea that a subject object is *truthy* and will show the template. When the directive emits a result the parent component can then emit `undefined` as the next value which will remove the template.

Comment: That's not taking care of setting the open property of `<vcd-modal>` I would still need to pass it separately. I'm not sure I understand it I guess. If every parent requires all that code, this is making it a lot harder. I'm looking to make it simpler on the parent.